# Invalid JSON format Datatable

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, datatable

I'm trying to implement sever side datatable, but it throws `Invalid JSON format` error.

CDN

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
```

HTML

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>EmployeeCode</th>
            <th>EmployeeName</th>
            <th>ManagerName</th>
            <th>DesignationName</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

JS

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "/api/url",
        "columns": [
            { data: "EmployeeCode" },
            { data: "EmployeeName" },
            { data: "ManagerName" },
            { data: "DesignationName" }
        ],
    } );
} );
</script>
```

JSON

```
{
  "Results":[{"EmployeeCode": "12345"}], // This is just a sample of data
  "CurrentPage": 1,
  "PageCount": 42,
  "PageSize": 10,
  "RecordCount": 417
}
```

Comment: Your JSON data is not clear, can you update with full complete data.

Comment: looks like `EmployeeCode` is missing quotes - they're required in JSON

Comment: @ic3b3rg This data is confidential I cannot post it here, but I can assure you that data is in proper JSON format, with quotes.

Comment: Let me introduce you to my friend https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @Lukman I have already tested this JSON DATA on http://json.parser.online.fr/, and it doesn't throws any error here

Answer (score 0):

it is clear what the issue is, looking at the JSON returned by the XHR/Ajax call to the server. It should just contain the expected data like this:

```
[
  {'EmployeeCode':12345,EmployeeName:'abcde',...},
  {'EmployeeCode':12346,EmployeeName:'fghij',...},
  ...
]
```

Rather your JSON contains other properties and the data is nested under the "Results" property. Also looking at the [documentation](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html), I think you need to format the JSON to contain a data property:

```
{
  "draw": 1,
  "recordsTotal": 57,
  "recordsFiltered": 57,
  "data": [
    [
      "12345",
      "John Smith",
      "Adam James",
      "Manager",
    ],
    ...
}
```

So as a simple fix use the 'dataSrc':'Results' property as suggested by Ankush in your datatable configuration.

Comment: I have huge number of data that I cannot post here, that's why I posted sample of json, and JSON is perfectly fine.

Comment: I think the same, is there any way to map JSON with Datatable? Ex. `data = results`

Comment: Just use the 'dataSrc' property

Answer (score 0):

Use `dataSrc` attribute to let datatable know from where to collect data:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "/api/url",
         "dataSrc": function (json) {
                   debugger;
          return json.data;
        },
        "columns": [
            { data: "EmployeeCode" },
            { data: "EmployeeName" },
            { data: "ManagerName" },
            { data: "DesignationName" }
        ],
    } );
} );
```

More detail about `dataSrc` can found [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc).

Comment: Used `"dataSrc": "Results"` Still facing the same issue.

Comment: I have updated the code. Now try to use dataSrc as mentioned in code & put a break-point over there to check what data you are receiving & then return array property.

Comment: no success, I guess I need to make changes in my API